# Php preg_match doesnt work with variable

Tags: php, arrays, regex

I have one array which contains multiple strings. I have another array which contain also strings but they are shorter. My goal is to check is there any partial match in the bigger array for every item from the smaller array. However preg_match doesnt work at all with variables. If I put raw input everything seems fine but otherwise results is false. I have tried almost every possible regex combination but without success. Sample code:

```
//Lets say $needle is 3333 and bigPatern has 10 records with 10 digits each, for example third record is 5125433331. I want to perform the partial match and get true
$needle = $smlPattern[0]; //debugging with first item from smaller array
$needle2 = "/$needle/"; // I tried [$needle], ^..&, to concatenate and etc
foreach ($bigPatern as $val)
{
if (preg_match($needle2, $val))
{
    echo "YES";
}
}
```

Any tips what Im doing wrong?

Comment: what is the value of `$needle` and `$bigPatern` and `$val`? Is `$bigPatern` a typo. Put something else in the `foreach` to check the program flow,

Comment: Could you please provide a reproducible snippet?

Comment: It works here http://rextester.com/TSNVJ40822

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please escape your regex input!

```
$needle2 = "/".preg_quote($needle,'/')."/"; //
```

Don't blindly add user input to your regex, much for the same reason you need to escape user input in SQL queries. In regex, the biggest issue is usually the [ReDoS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReDoS) problem, where a malicious user can create a specially crafted regex that will use hours, or more, to execute, stealing all the CPU from your server.

Comment: I forgot to trim the input... that was the issue. I was reading from a file and your tip reminded me. Thanks a lot this solved the issue and gave me little more information about ReDoS. My code actually reads from a file, and above sample is just a proof of concept, not the actual code.

Answer (score 1):

Main wrong thing in your example is to use regexp for checking the presence of a string. There is a [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) function for that.

```
if ( strpos($bigOne, $smallOne) !== false ) {
    echo "bigOne contains smallOne";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can even use `strpos` function to achieve the same purpose. It finds the position of the first occurrence of a substring in a string, and returns `false` if no match is found.

```
$needle = $smlPattern[0];
$needle2 = "needle";
foreach ($bigPatern as $val){
    if (strpos($val, $needle2) !== false){
        echo "YES";
    }
}
```